# JQuery select 2 of 3 links from repeating html structure

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select 2 of 3 existing `a` elements from a repeating HTML structure and having trouble designing an efficient jquery selector.

Here is the markup. I'm trying to select `Link 1`, `Link 2`, but not `Link 3`. Note that the entire HTML structure (`div.container`) could occur multiple times. If it does, I need Link 1 and Link 2 from all `container` classes.

**NOTE 1: I cannot modify the markup.**

**NOTE 2: I'd prefer the solution be completely selector based (and avoid calls to `.find()`, etc., as this selector has to be combined with another selector outside the scope of this question.**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>
        <a href="http://www.google.ca">Link 1</a>
    </h1>
    <div>
        <div class="left">
            <p>
                <a href="http://www.google.ca">Link 2</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <a href="http://www.google.ca">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a single `container` structure occurs, a simple selector is:

```
$(".container a:lt(2)");
```

However if multiple `container` structures exist, the above only selects Link 1 and Link 2 from the first container.

The below works for one or more `container` structures, but I don't like it. It seems inefficient to setup multiple css path selectors.

```
$(".container h1 a, .container .left a");
```

In verbose language, I would like to "select all `a` tags within class `container` not contained within class `right`. Is this possible? Or is the above selector using 2 CSS paths the best option.

[Test Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Tgr/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$(".container").find("a:lt(2)")
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Tgr/1/)

> have a separate selector outside the scope of this question, which is then combined with the selector from this question. Let's say $('.myOtherSelector, .selectorFromThisQuestion'); so I'd prefer this solution be a selector only. I can otherwise do $('.container').find('a:lt(2)').add('.myOtherSelector') to combine them but as you can see the first option is much simpler. As I said if it can't be done, I'll definitely use your solution/mark as answer. I'm just interested whether a straight selector can be used.

Alternatively as a workaround you can try like below if you want it in 1 line.. Note that this only will work for the presented markup. **Any markup change will break the code.**

```
$(".container :nth-child(1) a").css('background-color','red');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Tgr/3/)

Comment: thanks. This does work, however I should have been more clear in my question that ideally I'm looking for a selector alone, without calls to .find() or other functions. The selector to find these links is combined with another selector in my project, so adding further functions complicates it. I will upvote though as you did hit the mark as asked. I've updated the question.

Comment: @KP. I am not sure how it complicates it.. If you provide more information, we can try and find another way.

Comment: I have a separate selector outside the scope of this question, which is then combined with the selector from this question. Let's say `$('.myOtherSelector, .selectorFromThisQuestion');` so I'd prefer this solution be a selector only. I can otherwise do `$('.container').find('a:lt(2)').add('.myOtherSelector')` to combine them but as you can see the first option is much simpler. As I said if it can't be done, I'll definitely use your solution/mark as answer. I'm just interested whether a straight selector can be used.

Comment: Thanks very much. The markup shouldn't change so this will work great. Noting also Probocop's answer below works with some flexibility. I know the markup won't change though so I'll mark yours as answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:not` selector, as below:

```
$(".container a:not('.right a')")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. This works great. I've upvoted and wish I could also mark it as an alternative option to Vega's. Both are completely accurate for my needs.